# Assign objects to vector in for loop R

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm new to R and I am having some trouble. I created 10 samples(s1..s10) of random numbers

```
for(i in 1:numOfsam) {
    assign(paste("s",i,sep=""),rnorm(length,mu,sigma))

smp<-c(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9,s10)
```

I want to assign this samples to a vector, but it must be done in loop due to the number of samples can be larger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use `assign` until you are an experienced R programmer (and then you will need it very rarely). Here you could pre-allocate a matrix and fill it. The columns will correspond to your samples:

```
numOfsam <- 3
length <- 5
mu <- 2
sigma <- 0.1

result <- matrix(nrow = length, ncol = numOfsam)
set.seed(42) #for reproducibility
for (i in seq_len(numOfsam)) {
  result[,i] <- rnorm(length, mean = mu, sd = sigma)
}
result
#         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
#[1,] 2.137096 1.989388 2.130487
#[2,] 1.943530 2.151152 2.228665
#[3,] 2.036313 1.990534 1.861114
#[4,] 2.063286 2.201842 1.972121
#[5,] 2.040427 1.993729 1.986668
```

Of course you can get exactly the same result without a `for` loop:

```
set.seed(42) #for reproducibility
result2 <- matrix(rnorm(length * numOfsam, mean = mu, sd = sigma), ncol = numOfsam)
result2
#         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
#[1,] 2.137096 1.989388 2.130487
#[2,] 1.943530 2.151152 2.228665
#[3,] 2.036313 1.990534 1.861114
#[4,] 2.063286 2.201842 1.972121
#[5,] 2.040427 1.993729 1.986668
```